# ToListAsync repeating first item's data into every list item

Tags: mysql, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm running some very basic SQL against a MySql database, using `EntityFrameworkCore` and its `async` methods. When the data is returned using `ToListAsync()`, every single row is just a duplicate of the first, even through the row count itself is correct.

My class is defined as:

```
public class MyItem
{
    [Key] public Guid user_id { get; set; }
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string folder { get; set; }
}
```

Within the class itself, I have:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}
    ...
```

and the query itself runs in an async method:

```
public async Task<MyReturnObject> GetMyReturnObject(string userId)
{
    ...
    var sql = $"select user_id, item_id, folder from myItems where user_id = @p0";
    var myItemList = await this.MyItems.FromSql(sql, userId).ToListAsync();
    ...
}
```

Checking `myItemList` immediately after it's been populated shows a list of rows that has the correct number of items, but every single item is populated from the first row of data. The underlying data is distinct, and my obfuscation hasn't removed any joins in the SQL that could affect the returned data.

I suspect I'm misinterpreting how async and await are meant to be used with database queries, however I've been unable to spot where my mistake is.

Comment: Do you really need to pass in raw SQL? That negates many of the benefits of having an ORM in the first place. Instead just do `MyItems.Where(x => x.user_id == userId)` How are you consuming the results of this method? Are you sure you're using it correctly there?

Comment: @DavidG That's a good point. It makes certain parts (which I've omitted) easier, but if it comes to "working" vs "easier" then "working" obviously wins.

Comment: @DavidG The incorrect values are showing both in debug mode (with a breakpoint immediately after this `FromSql` line) and in the UI it returns data to, so I'm confident of what I'm seeing.

Comment: "Async" is rarely needed with MySQL.

Comment: As @IvanStoev said, your model is incorrect. Based on what you have posted above, there will be only 0/1 record not multiple duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `async` / `await`.

The key is the `[Key]` attribute of the `user_id` property. It's telling EF that the `user_id` property is the PK of the table, i.e. is *unique*. Hence your query is expected to return 0 or 1 records. If it returns more (as it seems), then during the materialization EF will consolidate the entity instance with the same PK, resulting in a list with one and the same entity instance, regardless of the query result.

Looking at the entity, most likely you need to mark it using composite PK by `(user_id, item_id)`, which currently can be done only with fluent API. So remove the `[Key]` attribute and use

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyItem>().HasKey(e => new { e.user_id, e.item_id });
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah! Well spotted, and thank you for the suggestion of using a composite PK.